# How to determine if zip is encrypted by AES

Tags: character-encoding, cryptography, winzip, password-protection, aes

I have to determine encryption method of ZIP files I'm receiving.
Mostly I'm interested to know if AES was used or not...

Any idea ?

Comment: Found that 7ZIP can display that....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It tells you where that data is located in the spec:  find on [this](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) page "AlgID     2 bytes  Encryption algorithm identifier" and read the surrounding text.